# why this onclick attribute of button does not work?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

```
var tbody = $("#queryModalTable tbody");
list_of_tasks.forEach(function (t) {

tbody.append(
 $(document.createElement("tr")).append(
        $(document.createElement("td")).text(t.task_id),
        $(document.createElement("td")).text(t.task_status),
        $(document.createElement("td")).text(t.task_operator),
        $(document.createElement("td")).text(t.number_of_hits),
        $(document.createElement("td")).text(t.finished_hits),
        $(document.createElement("td")).append(
           $(document.createElement("button"))
                .addClass("btn btn-primary")
                .attr("type", "button")
                .attr("onclick","showTaskResult(t)")
                .attr("data-toggle", "collapse")
                .attr("data-target", "#collapseExample")
                .attr("aria-expanded", "false")
                .attr("aria-controls", "collapseExample")
                .text("show task results")
              )
           )
      );

});
```

Just want to know why the showTaskResult(t) function could not be triggered, is there conflict between the onclick and "data-toggle", "collapse"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're adding the onclick as a string attribute, it is not evaluated in the current context, the `t` variable is not in scope when it is fired.

A solution is to assign the click handler like so:

```
$(document.createElement("button"))
    .addClass("btn btn-primary")
    ...
    ...
    ...
    .click(function(){
        showTaskResult(t);    
    })
```